# Sending mail with SmtpClient not working, while running the same code in different projects does

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2, smtpclient

I am working in Visual Studio 2012, On Windows 7,  I run the program on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, both are 64-bit.  I have been using the same code in many processes and I always has worked fine.  However, recently when I use the same code now I get the following exception,

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket
in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25
```

And the code,

```
public static void emailReport(string to, string from, string subject, 
    string body, string attachment, string hostAddress)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(hostAddress);
        foreach (string email in to.Split(','))
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
```

- Older processes that use this exact code still work and can send
  mail, using the same host address and port.
- Looking at the sockets
  with *netstat -o*, I can see that the socket is not being held by any
  process.
- .net Framework 4.5 is on both my local machine and the server.
- I have Visual Studio 2012 on the server and have tried recreating the project there to see if there is any change, there wasn't.
- I can connect, on the server, to the mail host using *telnet smtp.mydomain.com 25*

Essentially starting this week any new versions of applications (.exe) using this code don't send email, but old versions of the same applications do.
I suspect this is a problem with the environment I am running the process in or perhaps the way I am building the project.  I am not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: check your smtp server is working or not? 100% sure it is not valid smtp now

Comment: You don't have your `NetworkCredentials` defined to login to the server, which I'm assuming this application requires it.  You also don't have a port number defined, though it defaults to 25 so unless it actually is 25 it won't work.

Comment: Greg - 25 is the port I want to use and normally don't need to change the `NetworkCredentials`.  I would like to look up what these would be but the weird thing is, current processes that don't set these variables work fine.

Comment: @oldrustybucket Yeah, maybe so.  Are these applications apart of the same network, same server?  There is deviation that you aren't providing which makes this difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes everything is running on the server,  the email code won't run on my local machine as it is does not have permission to (when I test locally I just use outlook).  The server has been 'set up' to use this mail host.  I wish I could know what this deviation is,  I will try to talk to someone in the company to look for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to figure this out.  It was in-fact a firewall issue despite processes working some of the time.

The firewall had certain criteria to block suspicious file names.  I needed to rename the executable to something not suspicious or more reflective of what it does (i.e. "emailer")